# How to fix query problem on Azure CosmosDB that occurs only on collections with large data?

Tags: python, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I'm trying to read from a CosmosDB collection (`MachineCollection`) with a large amount of data (58 GB data; index-size 9 GB). Throughput is set to 1000 RU/s. The collection is partitioned with a Serial number, Read Location (WestEurope, NorthEurope), Write Location (WestEurope). Simultaneously to my reading attempts, the `MachineCollection` is fed with data every 20 seconds.

The problem is that I can not query any data via Python. If I execute the query on CosmosDB Data Explorer I get results in no time. (e.g. querying for a certain serial number).

For troubleshooting purposes, I have created a new Database (`TestDB`) and a `TestCollection`. In this `TestCollection`, there are 10 datasets of `MachineCollection`. If I try to read from this `MachineCollection` via Python it succeeds and I am able to save the data to CSV.

This makes me wonder why I am not able to query data from MachineCollection when configuring TestDB and TestCollection with the exact same properties.

What I have already tried for the querying via Python:

```
options['enableCrossPartitionQuery'] = True
Querying using PartitionKey:   options['partitionKey'] = 'certainSerialnumber'
```

Same as always. Works with TestCollection, but not with MachineCollection.

Any ideas on how to resolve this issue are highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, what you need to know is that Document DB imposes limits on `Response page size`. This link summarizes some of those limits: [Azure DocumentDb Storage Limits - what exactly do they mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40143986/azure-documentdb-storage-limits-what-exactly-do-they-mean)

Secondly, if you want to query large data from Document DB, you have to consider the query performance issue, please refer to this article:[Tuning query performance with Azure Cosmos DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-sql-query-metrics).

By looking at the [Document DB REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/documentdb/query-documents), you can observe several important parameters which has a significant impact on query operations : `x-ms-max-item-count, x-ms-continuation.`

As I know,Azure portal doesn't automatically help you optimize your SQL so you need to handle this in the sdk or rest api.

You could set value of [Max Item Count](http://Doesn't%20automatically%20help%20you%20optimize%20your%20SQL) and paginate your data using `continuation token`. The Document Db sdk supports reading paginated data seamlessly. You could refer to the snippet of python code as below:

```
q = client.QueryDocuments(collection_link, query, {'maxItemCount':10})
results_1 = q._fetch_function({'maxItemCount':10})
#this is a string representing a JSON object
token = results_1[1]['x-ms-continuation']
results_2 = q._fetch_function({'maxItemCount':10,'continuation':token})
```

Another case you could refer to:[How do I set continuation tokens for Cosmos DB queries sent by document_client objects in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47705124/how-do-i-set-continuation-tokens-for-cosmos-db-queries-sent-by-document-client-o)

Comment: @Dan Ok,if it works or any concern,please let me know.